# problem with roslib

Tags: ros, rosbridge, roslib, roslibjs, websocket

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i try to excute the script simple.html from robridge tutorial page. i have this error :

ReferenceError: ROSLIB is not defined

simple.html: in line 11

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206658/problem-with-roslib/) by [ahmedx724](https://answers.ros.org/users/22084/ahmedx724/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-04-05**:
Please edit your question to provide more details. You should include things such as links to the tutorial, versions of tools you're running and instructions how to reproduce your problem. Seehttp://wiki.ros.org/Support

**Comment by [salsalam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26207/salsalam/) on 2016-03-08**:
I am having the same problem.

Indigo, Ubuntu 14.04, Firefox 44.0.2
Tutorial simple.html can be found at https://github.com/RobotWebTools/roslibjs/blob/develop/examples/simple.html

The Firefox webconsole reports;
ReferenceError: ROSLIB is not defined (simple.html line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you download the `roslibjs` repository from source? The example file attempts to load the JS file locally from the source build. If you are trying to copy-and-paste the example and run it without the source code, you can change line 6 of the example to include the following:

`<script src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/roslibjs/current/roslib.min.js"></script>`

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2016-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0